# usestate variable shows undefined value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I'm getting an undefined error on `value` variable which is a state. when logging the `value` in the console, It initially takes the value from `props.value` inside the `useEffect`. But then in concurrent renders it's written `undefined` so I'm guessing `value` variable becomes undefined after that. But this issue is not there when removing the `value.length` code. then the undefined error doesn't happen and the `props.value` is inside the textarea. But I need the `value.length` code to determine some CSS classes. Hence I'm guessing before the value variable is set by `props.value`, `value.length code runs. But then the state default is set as "" so` value.length` should return 0 even if it runs first right? So I'm not understanding why my state variable value is becoming undefined in between.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TextArea = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(props.name, value);
  }, [value, props]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(props.value);
  }, [props.value]);

  return (
    <div className="input-box input-box--3">
      <textarea
        required
        name={props.name}
        type="text"
        rows={props.rows}
        value={value}
        onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
        className={
          console.log(value)
          // value.length === 0
          //   ? "input-box--field input-box--field--3"
          //   : "input-box--field input-box--field--3 input-box--field--3--not-empty"
        }
        autoComplete={props.autoComplete}
      />
      <span
        className={
          value.length === 0
            ? "input-box--placeholder"
            : "input-box--placeholder input-box--placeholder--not-empty"
        }
      >
        {props.placeholder}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextArea;
```

Comment: Does `event.target.value` when you try to set the value, is defined?

Comment: Apparently the props.value was not collected fast enough to be set before the condition props.value.length === 0 was checked so it was set as undefined for a few seconds which then created this issue I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value depends on the `value` prop, so if you'll pass something in this prop, it should work:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-cartwright-x6ldj0?file=/src/App.js

However, you can make it more bulletproof by checking if the passed prop is undefined:

```
  setValue(props.value ? props.value : "");
```